# Web Audio API — getting peak and RMS meter values

Tags: web-audio-api

I would like to generate accurate peak and RMS information from an `AudioNode`. Given the amount of smartness in Tone.js to avoid script processors whenever possible, I am surprised that [their volume meter](https://github.com/TONEnoTONE/Tone.js/blob/master/Tone/component/Meter.js) *does* use a script processor to calculate RMS volume.

I am thinking that it must be possible to translate the following SuperCollider code that I have used for years for reliable metering:

```scala
val sig   = In.ar("bus".ir, bus.numChannels)
val tr    = Impulse.kr(20)
val peak  = Peak.kr(sig, tr)
val rms   = A2K.kr(Lag.ar(sig.squared, 0.1))
SendReply.kr(tr, Flatten(Zip(peak, rms)), "/$meter")
```

That is I need a resetable running-max and a smoothing filter for squared input. The problem is that with the limited existing modules in Web Audio API, I would probably need something like a single-sample-delay feedback loop which doesn't exist.

Perhaps the RMS I can realise with a Gain and BiQuad stage? Any thoughts (also in terms of performance)? Any ideas how to get the running max (without script processor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an approximate RMS with a biquad, but you can't get running max without a script processor.

Comment: You can square the signal as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458161/web-audio-api-squaring-a-signal-by-using-a-gain. (Or use a waveshaper node.) A running mean can be done, I think, with a convolver node with a constant signal to sum the squares (and scale it), and then a waveshaper node can compute the square root.  But the max needs a script processor, as cwilso says.