# Web Audio API — squaring a signal by using a Gain

Tags: web-audio-api

Should it be possible to square a signal by creating a `Gain` instance and connecting the signal both to the gain input and amplitude control parameter? Because I am seeing odd results at least in Firefox. I can see that Tone.js uses a wave-shaper instead for a `pow` operation, so perhaps this is the way to go. But I'm curious, since the API says the `gain` parameter is audio-rate, obviously there must be some delays involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
var c = new AudioContext();
var o = c.createOscillator();
var g = c.createGain();
g.gain.value = 0;
g.connect(c.destination);
o.connect(g);
o.connect(g.gain);
o.start();
o.stop(c.currentTime + 2);
```

You can't tell from listening but if you paste the code into http://hoch.github.io/canopy/, you can see that the sine wave has been squared.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works to square a signal this way.  (I use it in my vocoder.)  There should be no delay in doing things this way.